# nginx php-fpm with dynamic url segments not being parsed by php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

so this one is a weird one! I have these nginx stanzas. I used an online tool to convert `.htaccess` rules into `nginx` capable ones.

```
location / {
        rewrite ^/(([^/]+/)*)login/$ /login.php?path=$1&$query_string break;
        rewrite ^/(([^/]+/)*)comment/$ /comment.php?path=$1&$query_string break;
        rewrite "^/([^/]+/){4}$" /asset.php break;
        rewrite ^/(\d\w+)/$ /public.php?ticket=$1 break;
        rewrite "^/(\d\w+)/([^/]+/){2}?$" /public-asset.php?ticket=$1 break;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^/(([^/]+/)*) /index.php?path=$1&$query_string break;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/vh1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

going to `https://example.test/` ok

going to `https://example.test/login/` all heck break loose and PHP code is flooded onto the screen.

The regex routing works because the redirects take place. but once the redirect it done, it's like the masked `.php` file is not caught. All this is fixed if I encapsulate the PHP checks within the `/` location block.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `rewrite ... break` when the rewritten URI is to be processed in a **different** `location` block.

Use: `rewrite...last`

---

Also, there is no need to tack `&$query_string` on the end of the rewritten URI, as `rewrite` will do it anyway **unless** the rewritten URI ends with a `?`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.